# Specifying when to drag a draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

Is it possible to make a div draggable and say that the div should only be dragged when the user clicks on a specific element within that div? I have a draggable div with a  header element.  I want dragging to happen only when the  element is clicked.

Here is the javascript where I make the div draggable.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#edit" ).resizable();
    $( "#edit" ).draggable();
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML for the div

```
<div class="demo">

<div id="edit" style="position:absolute; width: 250px; height: 550px;" class="comdiv">
    <h3 class="comhdr ui-widget-header">Sample</h3>

        <p id="heading" class="editableText ui-widget-content">Text for edits.</p> 

</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

http://jsbin.com/awihej/2/edit

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/pfs8a/38/ Most importantly, look for `.dragBox`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [handle](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-handle) option:

```
$("#edit").draggable({
    handle: "h3"
});
```

Or maybe:

```
$("#edit").draggable({
    handle: ".ui-widget-header"
});
```